# There are no addresses available for this application. Business Data Connectivity

Tags: bcs

I can't get the new Business data Connectivity Service I've just created to work. 
It says that it started, and I proceed to an IISRESET as said in a lot of blogs, but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any clue where it comes from ?

Thanks

Logs :

> Logging unknown/unexpected client side exception: SPEndpointAddressNotFoundException. This will cause this application server to be removed from the load balancer queue. Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEndpointAddressNotFoundException: Il n’existe aucune adresse disponible pour cette application.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoundRobinServiceLoadBalancer.BeginOperation()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceApplicationProxy.Execute[T](String operationName, UInt32 maxRunningTime, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation, Boolean performCanaryCheck, Boolean isChannelThatDelegatesIdentity)    d16f4978-035b-4072-b7b1-59d82af30da1

Comment: Any errors from logs you could share? Hard to know what it could be without some more info

Comment: Yep sorry, just added them in my edit

Answer (score 1):

Can you look to the Application Management > Services on Server, whether Service: Business Data Connectivity is really Started and correctly Running? Is for BDC Service used standalone registred managed account with correct password and with autochange password to False?